# Dynamically adding controls to a panel within a data repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a Data Repeater to which I need to add x number of  images depending on their existence in the database.

I need the images added within hyperlinks for Javascript functionality.  In order to dynamically add the hyperlinks and images I have placed them within a panel in the data repeater and am adding them in the ItemDataBound event.

The problem is that only the first image is being written to the datarepeater.

```
Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles myDataRepeater.ItemDataBound
    Dim myPanel As Panel = e.Item.FindControl("pnlImages")
    Dim myLink As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink
    Dim myImage As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image
    Dim myProperty As String = Request.QueryString("ID")

    Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/ftp/images/"))
    Dim fs_infos() As FileInfo = dirInfo.GetFiles("*" + myProperty.Substring(1) + "*")
    For Each fs_info As FileInfo In fs_infos
        If fs_info.Name.Substring(8, 1) <> "P" Then

            myLink.ID = fs_info.Name
            myLink.NavigateUrl = "~/ftp/images/" + fs_info.Name
            myLink.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return hs.expand(this)")
            myLink.Width = 90

            myImage.ID = "img" + fs_info.Name
            myImage.ImageUrl = "~/ftp/images/" + fs_info.Name
            myImage.Width = 80
            myImage.Height = 60
            myLink.Controls.Add(myImage)
            myPanel.Controls.Add(myLink)
        End If
    Next fs_info
    fs_infos = Nothing


End Sub
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong - or a better way of doing things?

Answer (score 1):

You create just one Link and one Image object and use it for each iteration. Move the dims of myLink and myImage into the if statement and everything should work.

Comment: yep.  or inside your loop have `myLink = New ...` and `myImage = New ...`